# Twilio Programmable Chat WebSocket connection

Tags: node.js, qt, twilio, twilio-api

I am working to integrate [Twilio Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat)  into a Qt/QML application - meaning I cannot readily use the [Javascript Client SDK](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.1/docs/). I would like to have features like typing indicator, token expiration notices, etc. handled in my client.

In the [examples](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js), the client sdk initiates a WebSocket connection directly to Twilio and receives events like token expiration, etc. directly.

Twilio seems to provide a number of SDKs that abstract the majority of features (read receipt, typing indicator, access-token), for Javascript, iOs, and Android.

However, it appears that their "server-side" wrappers (helper libraries) offer limited functionality only for accessing REST aspects of API, and not WebSockets.

As I am working in **QML** I cannot just drop a remote Javascript library into a webpage and start building a client (The Javascript inevitably does not act the same).

**Does Twilio provide any documentation for access it's Programmable Chat WebSocket connections directly? I could also build my own NodeJS WebSocket wrapper around a library, however, [twilio-node](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node) just looks like a wrapper around the REST API as well**.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The websocket API is not a documented API or protocol and it is not recommended to build against it as undocumented changes may break your implementation.

It is true that the server side libraries only cover the REST API. You can also [receive events from the Chat API using the webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/webhooks) that are available.

Comment: looking at the [webhooks documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/webhooks) I noticed: **Note: Only commands and events triggered from sdk clients endpoints will trigger the event callback (if configured). REST API actions will currently not trigger these.** So for example, if I use the REST API to create messages, I _wouldn't_ be able to listen for a webhook to notify users a new message has arrived?

Comment: No, but since you created the message from your server, you would already know that the user had a new message and be able to notify the user.